# WCF security best option for server to server communication over internet

Tags: c#, wcf, security

When some ASP.NET applications, all on dedicated server, need to communicate which security option is appropriate ?

Data to be transferred is small in amount; SSL, X509 certificate or any option is available.

The service should remain private between application servers. New server should be added to the cluster easily.

**EDIT:** All servers are communicating over internet (no VPN, no secure physical connection...)

Comment: Do you have the physical links between the nodes secured?

Comment: Are they communicating with each other, or through a pubsub hub?

Comment: They are in the same LAN or they will comunicate to each other over the internet?

Comment: @RobertoBr: No they are distributed over internet, on different data centers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your particular scenario I would say [Transport Security with Certificate Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731074.aspx)

However, it might be a good idea to peruse the [different scenarios and options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730301.aspx) available.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Message Security once you are communicating over internet.

Take a look at the Juwal Lowl framework for WCF that can be very helpful

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163382.aspx#S4

And here some arguents in favor to Message Security

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733137.aspx